# Using knockout mapping, how do I map a whole array attribute myself?

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

From my server I receive an object that looks something like this:

```
var fromServer = { 
    foo: "Some foo", 
    barArray: [ "bar1", "bar2", "bar3", "bar4", "bar5" ] 
};
```

Using the mapping plugin for knockout, I want to customize how the view model is constructed and break the array up into sub-arrays of length 2. Something like this:

```
viewModel: {
    foo: "Some foo",
    barArray: [ ["bar1", "bar2"], ["bar3", "bar4"], ["bar5"] ]
}
```

On my way there, I realized that that the `create` callback is called once per array item. Here is my view:

```
<h1 data-bind="text: foo"></h1>
<ul data-bind="foreach: barArray">
    <li data-bind="text: $data.name"></li>
</ul>
```

And the javascript:

```
var fromServer = { foo: "Some foo", barArray: [ "bar1", "bar2", "bar3", "bar4", "bar5" ] };

var mapping = {
    'barArray': { 
        create: function(options) {
            return new barModel("This is " + options.data);
        }
    }
};

var barModel = function(data) {
   this.name = data; 
};

var viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(fromServer, mapping);

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

[Here's a fiddle showing the behaviour](http://jsfiddle.net/nieldw/tnqEZ/)

Here's the **real** question: Using the `create` callback, can I access the whole array, rather than each element, one at at time? Or, am I approaching this in the wrong way?

Comment: Why do you want them broken up into arrays of two?

Comment: @PaulManzotti This is obviously not the real problem. I actually get an array of all the days in the month, with some data attached to each day, and I need to break that array into sub-arrays of 7 days so that I can render the calendar using templates, one week at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do this, for mapping objects from the root of the JSON

```
        var mapping = {
            '': { 
                create: function(options) {
                    return new .....
                }
            }
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html), the options parameter passed into the create method has two properties:

`data`: The JavaScript object containing the data for this child

`parent`: The parent object or array to which this child belongs

so you can access it using `options.parent`.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that, but even so, the callback will be executed once per element in the array, which is not desirable. I want to access the whole array, once.

Answer (score 0):

You can restructure your incoming array the way you would use it before creating your view model.
Rather than using array of data that are 'sematically grouped' in some way, you can turn it into 
array of objects with properties filled accordingly.

I assume your data somehow related to weekdays, so I created WeekViewModel that will hold data for each week day. Before mapping data to viewmodel, I process if with ProcessBeforeCreatingViewModel function:

```
function WeekViewModel(data) {
    var self = this;
    ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, self);
}

function ProcessBeforeCreatingViewModel(data) {

 var tempObj = null;

 var data_processed = {
    foo: data ? data.foo : '',
    barArray: []
 };

 if (data && data.barArray) {

    data.barArray.forEach(function (barItem, index) {

        if (index % days.length == 0) {
            tempObj = {};
            days.forEach(function (dayName) {
                tempObj[dayName] = undefined;
            });
            data_processed.barArray.push(tempObj);
        }

        tempObj[days[index]] = barItem;
    });
 }

 return data_processed;
}


var mapping = {
    'barArray': { 
        'create': function(options) {
            return new WeekViewModel(options.data);
        }
    }
};

var fromServer_Processed = ProcessBeforeCreatingViewModel(fromServer);

var viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(fromServer_Processed, mapping);

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JeJKP/

Comment: Rustam, thanks for your answer, it was definitely helpful! However, I think @PabloRodríguez's answer addressed the crux of my question.